# How to convert Calendar to Date in Kotlin?

Tags: android, date, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to add one month to a date with Calendar.getInstance() but I can't figure out why there is error "java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Number" when trying to get the Calendar to a Date object.

Here's the source code that I am using :

```
    val date = Date()
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = date
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
    val datePlusOneMonth: Date = cal.time
```

Comment: The code you provided works fine on my side. Maybe error appears somewhere else in your code? Please check logs and look for the line number of the error

Comment: cal.time = date has not need here, otherwise what line gives you this error ?

Comment: The error happens on val datePlusOneMonth: Date = cal.time

Comment: Sergey, are you sure that it runs ok ? Because the exception does not trigger any bug in the application. It is only when I put a breakpoint and then go to Evaluate Expression window that I see the error when calling cal.time

Comment: Amine, you say right, cal.time = Date is not needed. Thanks. (Error still happening anyway)

Comment: Yes, the code runs fine on my side

Comment: So you have a value in datePlusOneMonth ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v9cgM2O

Comment: Yes I have. You can set log after line `val datePlusOneMonth: Date = cal.time` and check it

Comment: One thing I find bizarre is that when adding a try/catch block, then the code does not go in the catch block...

Comment: Because it is not throwing the exception)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you Sergey... The code runs ok. But I have been disappointed because I added a useless line of code in order to debug and I had put a breakpoint on it :

```
val datePlusOneMonth: Date = cal.time
val ok = false
```

And I had put the breakpoint on the "val ok = false" and the debugger never stopped on "val ok = false" because "ok" was never used.

Then to have the debugger stop on "val ok = false" I had to do the following :

```
val datePlusOneMonth: Date = cal.time
val ok = false
val ok2 = ok
```

And then I could add the breakpoing on "val ok = false" and yes the code runs well.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
val datePlusOneMonth = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
    time
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but we figured out that my code runs correctly. Anyway I'll consider this next time.